# Maven pom profile activation ignoring case

Tags: maven, selenium

I'm learning selenium, maven and junit, and I've made a small test project.
Everything works fine except for one detail, I'm trying to choose my webdriver as a parameter, so I've made two profiles in my pom, one for firefox, one for chrome.
In my test, in @Before, I've made a switch with an ignorecase on the browser variable :
    String browser=System.getProperty("browser");
And I've made this in my pom :

```
<activation>
    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        <property>
            <name>browser</name>
            <value>firefox</value>
        </property>
</activation>
```

Problem is, if I call

```
mvn clean test -Dbrowser=firefox
```

it works, but with

```
mvn clean test -Dbrowser=Firefox
```

it doesn't works, because pom is waiting for firefox.
Is there a way to ignore case in pom activation properties ?
If not, is there a workaround for my problem ?
Thanks

Comment: not familiar with pom, but in `xml` you are setting it to `false` by default.

Comment: yes, it's on purpose, I've two profiles, one for Chrome and one for Firefox, my Chrome one is activeByDefault, when I there's "firefox" in the "browser" property, it will switch to the firefox profile. My problem is, it doesn't works if I call "Firefox" instead, and I don't know how to make it not case sensitive.

Comment: Are u ignoring case in switch case? Can u show ur switch case code?

Comment: Thanks, but after further investigation, it seems that what I was trying to do is just impossible.